# Can I cast an unknown object to an interface so I can access its properties in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, interface

I'm trying to not repeat code, so I have a method that does a quick transform on the property of an interface.

I have 3 concrete classes that make use of this interface, and I want them all to be able to use this method.

The problem comes when I get one of these objects out of Session. I don't see any way to cast it properly.

```
public ActionResult GetItems()
{
     details = (IHeader<IDetail>)Session["SelectedHeader"].Details // Throws invalid cast
     return Json(details);
}

// My interface and class examples:
interface IHeader<T> where T: IDetail
{
     IList<T> Details { get; set; }
}

class ConcreteHeader : IHeader<ConcreteDetail>
{
     public IList<ConcreteDetail> Items { get; set; }
}

class ConcreteDetail : IDetail
{
    ...
}
```

I can't use generics because this is an action method in ASP.NET MVC 3 (unless there is a trick to that). Is this possible, or do I have to write a method for each class?

**EDIT: Not sure if this is clear from original question:**

What goes into session is any one of the concrete objects:

```
Session["SelectedHeader"] = new ConcreteHeader() { Details = new List<ConcreteDetail>() };
```

Comment: You're `ConcreteHeader` does not implement `IDetail`, however you have a generic constraint of `T : IDetail`. How does this even compile?

Comment: @m-y, shouldn't `ConcreteDetail` implement `IDetail`?

Comment: @Saeb yes, and it does. I can put it in for clarification.

Comment: @IronicMuffin, no need. I was replying to m-y's question.

Comment: @IronicMuffin: if you implement `IDetail` as an abstract class, the casting will work. Just finished testing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4.0, simply cast using the `dynamic` keyword to ensure proper automagical type resolution:

```
// note intellisense won't work when you use dynamic keyword...
var details = ((dynamic)Session["SelectedHeader"]).Details;
```

Comment: Because your answer is wrong. _"so the IHeader<IDetail> object should persist without issues"_ [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9824219/590790).

Comment: Well I guess I'm not sure. You're saying, don't use an interface at all for the detail record?

Comment: @IronicMuffin: I *was* saying don't declare `IDetail` as an interface, but please look at my updated remark regarding `dynamic`.

Comment: Oooh, `dynamic`. Didn't think of that. I still need to toy around with that keyword. Using co- and contraviance is still the way to go if you would be able to fit it into the design somehow.

Answer (score 5):

You need to wrap your cast with parentheses:

```
details = ((IHeader<IDetail>)Session["SelectedHeader"]).Details;
```

Comment: While you are correct with my misplaced parens, it still throws a cast exception: `Cannot cast 'Session["SelectedHeader"]' (which has an actual type of 'ConcreteHeader') to 'IHeader<IDetail>'`

Comment: Try using the out keyword on `IHeader<out T>`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you just ran into the wonderful world of co- and contravariance. I wrote [a blog post about it](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2011/05/23/casting-generic-types/) which tries to explain it as simple as I could.

Bottom line: you can't cast `IHeader<ConcreteDetail>` to `IHeader<IDetail>` prior to .NET 4.0.

Starting from .NET 4.0 you can use the [`in`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx) and [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) keywords in order to allow this. You could possibly define your interface as `interface IHeader<out T>`.

In case you don't use .NET 4.0 yet, you can work around the issue by creating a new lambda:

`details = () => Session["SelectedHeader"].Details;`

Comment: I've experimented with that before with little luck. I added it now, and got the following: `Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'IHeader<T>.Details'. 'T' is covariant.` I wonder if it is becuase `IList<T>` does not support variance?

Comment: @IronicMuffin Well, your variance still needs to be valid of course. That's why I said it was a possibility, not a guarantee. ;p I'm not 100% sure as I don't have the time to look into it in detail now, but probably `IList<>` is the problem yes. In order to use `out`, _"A type is returned from a class. (e.g. return value) The type should be the same type, meaning it is also any base type of that type."_. The type should **only** be used as 'output'. More detail is in the blog post I wrote, and of course in the msdn documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a read. This stuff is tough to ramp up on. My current work around is to have separate methods to pull the objects out of session, then call a method with the bulk of the logic that takes the interface as a param.

Comment: @IronicMuffin I know it's difficult to grasp at first, especially with the esoteric terminology used in the documentation. :) That's why I wrote that blog post, to learn about it myself, and to explain it in a more humane way. My guess is you'll have to define an extra interface _which is_ out only, which you can then make contravariant ... (or was it co?) .... out. :) List isn't out only since you can also add elements to a list ...